# Web browser can access webpages but games can't access servers that are not in my LAN

Tags: networking

The title tells everything: I can access websites using the browser, connect to servers within my LAN network, but I can't connect to servers that are not connected to my router.

I use:

```
   computer 1) wired connection - Windows 7
   computer 2) wireless connection - Ubuntu 13.10
```

This issue occurs on both machines.

The games I tried this on: Minecraft, Starmade, Ghost recon online and Sprial knights.

Comment: Are you at home? School? Work? Friends' house?

Comment: What are your firewall settings? It's 90% certain that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about lan connection, not game itself

Comment: @tombull89 Home

Comment: @Michel But where to ask it then?

Comment: @iani You can try asking this at SuperUser, but make sure to include more information, as there probably isn't enough here to diagnose and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As this is happening across two different computers, I suggest it might be a ports issue. Make sure the ports for the games you want to play are open.

[This site](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) is a good place to start if you don't know what to do, and [this page](http://portforward.com/cports.htm) is useful in working out which ports each game requires.

Alternatively, it could possibly be a firewall issue if both your systems are running the same software (But I can't help with that without more information)